# spring data jpa `@EntityGraph` not work as expected

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I've been encountering a issue with `@EntityGraph` in Spring Data Jpa not functioning as i expected. see my project structure:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Board extends BaseTimeEntity {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "writer_id")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private User user;

    // others
}

@Entity
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class User extends BaseTimeEntity {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    // others 
}
```

These are the simplified entities and their relationship. The issue is with the following repository method:

```
@Repository
public interface BoardJpaRepository extends JpaRepository<Board, Long> {
    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"user"})
    Optional<Board> findById(Long id);
}
```

I intended to fetch both Board and User using @EntityGraph in the findById method, but the executed query only fetches the Board:

```
select
    b1_0.id,
    b1_0.content,
    b1_0.create_date,
    b1_0.modified_date,
    b1_0.title,
    b1_0.writer_id,
    b1_0.views 
from
    board b1_0 
where
    b1_0.id in (?,?,?)
```

Moreover, when I use @EntityGraph in additional query methods in the BoardRepository, it works as expected:

```
@EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"user"})
Page<Board> findAll(Pageable pageable);

@EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"user"})
@Query("select b from Board b where b.user.username like %:username%")
Page<Board> findAllByUsernameLike(@Param(value = "username") String username, Pageable pageable);

@EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"user"})
@Query("select b from Board b where b.title like %:title%")
Page<Board> findAllByTitleLike(@Param(value = "title") String title, Pageable pageable);

@EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"user"})
@Query("select b from Board b where b.content like %:content%")
Page<Board> findAllByContentLike(@Param(value = "content")
```

```
    select
        b1_0.id,
        b1_0.content,
        b1_0.create_date,
        b1_0.modified_date,
        b1_0.title,
        u1_0.id,
        u1_0.create_date,
        u1_0.email,
        u1_0.is_account_non_expired,
        u1_0.is_account_non_locked,
        u1_0.is_credentials_non_expired,
        u1_0.is_enabled,
        u1_0.modified_date,
        u1_0.name,
        u1_0.password,
        u1_0.username,
        b1_0.views 
    from
        board b1_0 
    join
        user u1_0 
            on u1_0.id=b1_0.writer_id 
    where
        u1_0.username like concat('%',?,'%') escape '' limit ?,?
```

My current versions are:

- java 17
- spring boot 3.1.1
- hibernate core 6.2.5.Final

However, when I update Spring Boot to 3.2.0 and Hibernate Core to 6.3.1.Final, the issue seems to be resolved:

```
    select
        b1_0.id,
        b1_0.content,
        b1_0.create_date,
        b1_0.modified_date,
        b1_0.title,
        u1_0.id,
        u1_0.create_date,
        u1_0.email,
        u1_0.is_account_non_expired,
        u1_0.is_account_non_locked,
        u1_0.is_credentials_non_expired,
        u1_0.is_enabled,
        u1_0.modified_date,
        u1_0.name,
        u1_0.password,
        u1_0.username,
        b1_0.views 
    from
        board b1_0 
    left join
        user u1_0 
            on u1_0.id=b1_0.writer_id 
    where
        b1_0.id=?
```

The query is generated correctly, and the in clause that was declared due to Spring Batch also seems to change.

I'm hesitant to simply attribute this to a version issue, as it doesn't feel like a resolved problem. I'm curious if this is indeed a version-related issue, and if so, are there any related links or documentation? Additionally, I'm interested in knowing if there's a solution for the original version.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that the problem is with the hibernate version, its related to the fetchtype, that you are using the the join

If you use, fetch type as eager

```
@JoinColumn(name = "writer_id")
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private User user
```

The user object will be fetched along with the Board Object.

I am not sure on why it is fetching with the user object with the 6.3.1 version.

If may want to try

```
@EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"board.user"})
```

Comment: I have learned to set the join configuration for entity relationships to 'LAZY' by default. I use 'fetch join' or 'spring batch size' to retrieve data as needed. Therefore, I'm not sure if using 'EAGER' fetching is the right approach.

Comment: Thats right, you should set it to 'LAZY' by default.

Comment: so.. what should i do..?

Comment: Try @EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"board.user"})